# Why does this div appear so far right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have some problem with a div in bootstrap that appears strange.

Why is the input-text so far right?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <input type="text" value="test">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/eA5Uts8pxe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div class = "pull-right"` has a property `float: right!important;`

That over-writes everything else. Hence your textbox is so far right. Exclude that property or change it to `float:left` or set a `margin-left` and you get what you desire. Or, don't user "pull-right" class and make/user a "pull-left" class.

Example:-

if you change

```
.pull-right 
{
 float: left! important;
}
```

then you will see a significant difference in how the textbox is aligned on the horizontal plane. Let me know if you need further explanantion.

You can also try something like this:-

```
.pull-right
{
 margin-left: 70%;
}
```

But this is a bit of a hack. But it works well.:)

**Edit:-**

Make the `"div class = container"`:-

```
.container
{
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I want the input-text to be aligned to the right in the "well". But not "too much" as in my example. How can I write the css? If I change to float:left it will be align to left.

Comment: well it depends on what you mean by Right...? float: right makes it extreme right... however if you want the textbox to be set somewhat to the right...experiment with: "margin-left: 70%"

Comment: Has anything to do with my structure? Look at this: http://www.bootply.com/BG7hw58GWG - the red div is so wide. Why?

Comment: Ok, If you want to leave everything as it is... and want to fit the 'red' div inside its parent div 'container'... use the css code from my Edited post... you set the display style on your 'container' div to inline. That works well.